# Unable to clone with git+ssh

Tags: git, ssh

I'd need to clone a repository through git+ssh (git+ssh://git.host.repository.com). It fails as it uses my OS username instead of my organization user's name.

```
Cloning into 'project.name'...
francesco@git.host.repository.com's password:
```

There "francesco" is my OS account name, which obviously fails to login.
Within ~/.ssh/config I have added:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

But it didn't work. Also I've tried to update the key (which contains my corporate account):

```
touch ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

It still attempts to use the OS username to login and not the username contained in the public key.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should edit for ssh config confile similar to below. `User` can enforce the user to use for `ssh`.

```
Host git.host.repository.com
  HostName git.host.repository.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github/id_rsa
```